# Bidual of a WSC space

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $E$ be a Banach space which is weakly sequentially complete (i.e. each weak Cauchy sequence converges weakly). Must $E^{**}$ be weakly sequentially complete either? Of course, this question is interesting only for non-reflexive spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true.

I reproduce Remark 3. on page 101 (in the [section on Banach lattices](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0066871)) of [Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0066864) (in the old Springer Lecture Notes **338** edition):

[image: Remark 3 of Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri]

Reference [80] is:

William B. Johnson, *[A complementary universal conjugate Banach space and its relation to the approximation problem](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02762804)*, Israel Journal of Mathematics **13**(3-4) (1972), 301–310.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely brilliant!

Comment: Thanks, glad you liked it, but credit is fully due to Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri and Johnson :)